# Translate role name in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

In users model I add role:

```
  Roles = [:registered, :banned, :admin ]

  def is?( requested_role )
    self.role == requested_role.to_s
  end
```

How I can translate role name in veiw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a translation in `config/locales/en.yml` and give it a custom name:

```
en:
  models:
    user:
      roles:
        registered: 'Registered'
        banned: 'Banned'
        admin: 'Administrator'
```

Then call it

```
I18n.t("models.user.roles.#{user.role}")
```

Comment: Thanks, It works! How can translate in form? `= f.collection_select(:role, User::Roles, :to_s, lambda{|i| i.to_s.humanize})`